# LSZ formula for initial and final one particle states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, correlation-functions, s-matrix-theory

The LSZ formula for a real scalar field $\varphi$ is (Srednicki 5.24)
$$
\left<f|i\right>=i^{n+n'}\int d^4x_1e^{ik_1x_1}(-\partial_1^2+m^2)...\\
\quad d^4x'_1e^{ik'_1x'_1}(-\partial_{1'}^2+m^2)...\\
\quad \times \left<0|T\varphi(x_1)...\varphi(x_1')...|0\right>.\tag{5.24}$$
When we have just one particle in the initial state (say $|k\big>$) and one particle in the final state (say $|k'\big>$), this reduces to
$$
\left<k'|k\right>=i^{2}\int d^4xe^{ikx}(-\partial^2+m^2)
d^4x'e^{ik'x'}(-\partial'^2+m^2)\left<0|T\varphi(x)\varphi(x')|0\right>\\
\quad =i^{2}\int d^4xe^{ikx}(-\partial^2+m^2)
d^4x'e^{ik'x'}(-\partial'^2+m^2)\Delta_F(x-x'),$$
where $\Delta_F(x-x')$ is the Feynman propagator. By definition,
$$
\left<k'|k\right>=i^{2}\int d^4xe^{ikx}(-\partial^2+m^2)
d^4x'e^{ik'x'}\delta(x-x')\\
=i^{2}\int d^4xe^{ikx}(-\partial^2+m^2)
e^{ik'x}.$$
But $(-\partial^2+m^2)e^{ik'x}=0$, so $\left<k'|k\right>=0$. Nonetheless, in (5.5) we have
$$\left<k|k'\right>=(2\pi)^32\omega\delta^3(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}').\tag{5.5}$$

Is this a misuse of the LSZ formula? Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 3):

The LSZ theorem basically says that if you take the Fourier-transform of an $N$-point function $\langle \phi_1\phi_2...\rangle$ and send the momenta on-shell, you will see a product of simple poles $(p_i^2-m^2)^{-1}$ for each momenta, and that the residue of this pole will be the **connected scattering amplitude for asymptotic particles with said momenta.**

More precisely this means that for the Fourier-transformed $N$-point function
$$iG(p_n)=\prod_{n}\int d^3x_n e^{\pm ip_n x_n}\langle \phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)...\phi(x_n)\rangle$$
if we take the limit where the momenta go on-shell we will have
$$\lim_{p_n\to m^2}iG(p_n) \to \mathcal{A}(p_n)\left(\prod_n \frac{i}{p_n^2-m^2}\right)+\text{finite terms}$$ The $\mathcal{A}$ here is exactly what you referred to as $\langle i|f \rangle$. Now, in the case of $n=2$ our function $iG$ does not have this pole structure, in fact it simply has one factor of $(p^2-m^2)^{-1}$ and so the LSZ theorem correctly gives us $\mathcal{A}=0$.

Comment: In Greiner's Field Quantization Section 9.4 we see that LSZ excludes the case where particles in the intial and final states have the same momenta. Is that what you mean with connected scattering amplitudes? I think "disconnected" means some particles just "run through", which is the only possible scenario for initial and final one particle states. (?)

Comment: No, connected means that all the initial particles interact with each other instead of interacting in separate clusters. More precisely this means that the scattering amplitude has a single momentum-conserving delta function involving all asymptotic momenta. Roughly this means that the feynman diagrams are also connected graphs.